# Convert datatable to json format

Tags: json, vb.net, web-services

I have to convert Data table to JSON format at vb.net. I have written the code for that, but, I want in another format.
I have added the dll NewtonSoft.json and fill datatable from database for that,
The code I have written...
''''My dt is filled with data. I have written code in web service

```
Dim jsonString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)
```

I get the output like -

```
{"people":[{"ref":"108414","first_name":"George","last_name":"Buss","display_name":"George Buss","title":"Director of Experience & Education","organization_name":"Minnetrista","bio":"","address":"","city":null,"state":"IN","zipcode":"","country":"United States","phone_work":"","email":"","website":"","tags":"[Speaker,Attendees]","presenter_at":"[2307,8976]","organization_ref":"36441"}] }
```

but The `"tags"` value `"[Speaker,Attendees]"` in place of this i need in 
`"tags":["Speaker","Attendees"]` and same for presenter_at also

From my code I have directly taken datatable and convert it into json. But for this I think  to modified json data because this data not static it comes from a database. And I will change person by person. Does anyone know the solution, Please help me with this.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the value in your database for "tags":"[Speaker,Attendees]"

Comment: same speaker and attendees and column name as tags, I have joined this with COALESCE at SQL server query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
                }
                parentRow.Add(childRow);
            }
            return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
        }
```

This method Return json string.
i hope it's help you.